# Program compiling but not printing results

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I have been trying to write a program in Fortran77 and am not able to finish it up, so I need a bit help to make it work.
At first I am just trying to open a .txt file read the file and write the file.
the .txt file is of the format shown below.

```
001,0.02014,3.1217    
002,0.09611,3.1203    
003,0.23753,3.1128
004,0.45527,3.0884    
005,0.75772,3.0285
```

where the first column is integer and the second column coma separated contains a real number with 5 digits after the decimal point and third column again a real number with four digits after the decimal point.

My program looks as follows:

```
      PROGRAM FIRST
      IMPLICIT NONE

      REAL,DIMENSION(304,3)::A 

      OPEN(UNIT =7 , FILE = "Pressure_values.txt",
     1 FORM = "FORMATTED", STATUS = "OLD", ACTION = "READ") 

      READ(*,100) ((A(I,J),J=1,3), I=1,304) 

      WRITE(*,100) ((A(I,J),J=1,3), I=1,304)

   100 FORMAT(I3,F10.5,F10.4)

      STOP

      END
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I've added four blanks to each line to mark as code.  I've just guessed that your text file has no blank lines - please revert if it does (but solve the indentation after that).  This means you should also check whether I've accurately captured your fixed-form code (I'm worried about that `100` that is sticking in a bad place).

Comment: When you run or compile this, what output (if any) do you see?  Are there any messages, complaints?

Comment: That's not FORTRAN77, `implicit none` was introduced in the 90 standard.

Comment: I believe the `::` as well. `implicit none` was a quite common extension though.

Answer (score 3):

You are not reading from the file. You need to read from unit 7.

```
read(7,100)
```

Answer (score 0):

your code:

```
READ(*,100) ((A(I,J),J=1,3), I=1,304)
```

means "read from STDIN with format No.100", not the file you just opened. STDIN normally means the keyboard input stream. use:

```
READ(7,100) ((A(I,J),J=1,3), I=1,304)
```

instead.